# Running a JAR file, or a JAR converted to EXE will result in a Malware Message

Tags: java, jar, exe, antivirus, malware

When i'm/others is running the JAR or the converted JAR to an EXE on they computer, they get an Malware virus message, from they antivirus program, saying the file is dangerous.

What is it, that is casuing such a problem with JARs in generel? Is there a fix for it? I have searched through google now, and i can't seem to find a solution.

The program im using to convert is JarSplice (http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice)

It's nothing dangerous java code, it's just a plain hello world application.

I'm trying to run it on a Windows machine. I've tested it on a few other Windows pcs and they are saying the exact same. Dangerous!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be many different reasons for this, but on Windows the most common reason is that the Jar/Exe isn't properly signed.

I would also say that probably your program is matching a signature from a known virus by some unfortunate coincidence.  However a Hello World program is not likely for this to occur.